# firefox shows black 1px line on top of backgroundimage

Tags: css, firefox, border, background-image

I have the issue, that Firefox 31.0 (chrome and safari are fine) renders a 1px-wide border on top of every div which holds a background-image.

I tried already a few things like:

```
background-color: #F5F5F5;
border: 0px none #F5F5F5;
```

But it doesn't change the result. Strangely, the line disappears when I change those values in the inspector of ff.

The whole css looks like this:

[image: css appearance]

If you like, you can watch it live her: http://larserbach.com (The brighter the image the more obvious it becomes).

I'm glad, if you can offer me a fix to this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: JSBin please? The site no longer seems to be working.

Comment: Strange, it works fine here.
Just retested it in all 3 browsers I have - IE not included